# Javascript - inverting regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, inversion

My starting string is

```
alpha < beta < gamma < delta < epsi
```

I want to capture single tokens alpha,beta, ...

In one such expression, there might be also the possibily for operators to be referenced as 'lt','gt' and I have applied this regular expression so far.

```
/[^(\<\=?|\>\=?|==\ )|^(eq|lt|gt)]/g
```

This expression does not detect 'eq', 'lt', 'gt' as bounded words, but just 'e', 'q', 'l', 't', 'g'.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Character classes are not groups, they match a single character.

Comment: You can manage this particular string with `'alpha < beta < gamma < delta < epsi'.split(' < ')` No regular expressions, cheap and dirty.

Comment: Please post the whole relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Just do splitting on the boundaries you mentioned and note that use character classes only for orring each char sepearately. If you want to apply OR on group of characters then you must go with capturing group `(....)` or non-capturing group `(?:...)`

```js
var s = 'alpha < beta < gamma < delta < epsi'
alert(s.split(/\s*(?:\b(?:eq|lt|gt)\b|[<>]=?|==)\s*/))
```

Comment: Good !
I can't use the split command this way, because I need a same regular expression for different needs. But I merged your solution with mine and I obtained

/[^(\<\=?|\>\=?|==\ )]|^[\b(?:eq|lt|gt)\b]/g

which works fine as desired. Thank you !

Comment: @SandroRosa: No, you have got it wrong. The `\b` in `[\b(?:eq|lt|gt)\b]` means a backspace symbol. In the suggestion, it is outside the character class, a word boundary. Well, you regex is wrong. Read my comment, check the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Your're right: I'm a newbie with regular expressions. I will use split cmd. Your snippet still works great !